# Change a dictionary's key in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

How can I change a dictionary's key for a particular value? I can't just change `dict[i]` to `dict[i+1]` because that changes the *value* for that particular key. And there's no `dict.updateKeyForValue()` like there is a `dict.updateValueForKey()`.

Because my keys are `Int`'s and all out of order, I can't modify the entire key-value pair by looping through because I may override a pair that the loop hasn't reached yet. Is there a simpler way? Feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: You're missing the fact that dictionary keys are immutable. It sounds like a dictionary is not the appropriate data structure for whatever you're doing.

Comment: Just set it nil and add a new key

Comment: dict[i+1] = dict[i].

Comment: No way to change keys, but you can store the object at a particular key in another constant, then remove the value for that particular key and then re-add it with a new key. Something like `let theValue = myDict[key]; myDict.removeValueForKey(key); myDict[newKey] = theValue;`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Swift 3**

```
func switchKey<T, U>(_ myDict: inout [T:U], fromKey: T, toKey: T) {
    if let entry = myDict.removeValue(forKey: fromKey) {
        myDict[toKey] = entry
    }
}  

var dict = [Int:String]()

dict[1] = "World"
dict[2] = "Hello"

switchKey(&dict, fromKey: 1, toKey: 3)
print(dict) /* 2: "Hello"
               3: "World" */
```

**Swift 2**

```
func switchKey<T, U>(inout myDict: [T:U], fromKey: T, toKey: T) {
    if let entry = myDict.removeValueForKey(fromKey) {
        myDict[toKey] = entry
    }
}    

var dict = [Int:String]()

dict[1] = "World"
dict[2] = "Hello"

switchKey(&dict, fromKey: 1, toKey: 3)
print(dict) /* 2: "Hello"
               3: "World" */
```

Comment: Works For Swift 4 too :)

Answer (score 10):

I'm personally using an extension which imo makes it easier :D

```
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func switchKey(fromKey: Key, toKey: Key) {
        if let entry = removeValue(forKey: fromKey) {
            self[toKey] = entry
        }
    }
}
```

Then to use it:

```
var dict = [Int:String]()

dict[1] = "World"
dict[2] = "Hello"

dict.switchKey(fromKey: 1, toKey: 3)
print(dict) /* 2: "Hello"
               3: "World" */
```